# What is this 1950s brass door catch called

Tags: doors, latches

I'm looking for a replacement for the pictured 1950s internal door catch.  I can't find one, and don't know what they're called.  I've tried "gravity catch" and "teardrop catch" but those are not the same thing.  Reverse image search isn't helping either.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Might look nice, but I have a feeling that they might be not allowed now since a person inside could not open the door easily.

Comment: Cast a new one is an option.

Answer (score 3):

That is an antique cabinet door latch called a Hoosier Cabinet Latch. If you want a similar latch you could contact the House of Antiques Hardware at 888-223-2545 or at Van Dyke's Restorers, 1-800-237-8833 This is what I found when I Googled antique cabinet door latch.  hope this helps.

Comment: Don't think the OP will be visiting House of Antiques in person...

Answer (score 3):

So another option instead of casting a new one is to cut that worn part off, then drill and tap it to receive a new threaded bit cut to length.

Should work well.

Comment: Good idea, unfortunately the one I want to replace is broken beyond any repair (I posted that photo so you could see what it looks like)

Comment: @aucuparia Answers are based on the evidence provided, can’t do more than that.